# Installed 11.04 flickers horribly

Tags: 11.04, unity, drivers, compiz, hardware

I installed ubuntu 11.04 yesterday and I can only use ubuntu classic with no effects, because when I go on the normal ubuntu it flickers and stuff. My card is intel 82865G. I have tried adding i915 modeset or something to the grub but it makes my resolution REALLY small. I don't know what to do. This never happened in 9.10 10.04 or 10.10.

Comment: Welcome to the club. Same problem on every PC I've tested 11.04 on.

Comment: I know it sucks its really annoying.

Comment: Uhh... how do you do that?

Comment: @Uri Add instructions on how to do that please?

Comment: @jrg type in the terminal sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudp apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @Uri I meant in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of these, or both:

Add this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or Downgrade Compiz to it's previous version as explained [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-downgrade-to-compiz-086-in.html), by doing this Unity won't be available anymore though.

```
sudo apt-get purge compiz compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-main && sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:guido-iodice/compiz-0.8.6-natty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compiz-fusion-plugins-main   compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-unsupported compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compizconfig-backend-gconf compizconfig-settings-manager  libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 python-compizconfig
```